# NGINX Как перенаправить запрос на PHP-FPM если *.png не найден?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Подскажите, как в Nginx перенаправить запрос на PHP-FPM, если файл с расширением *.png не найден? У меня файл генерируется "на лету" скриптом. NGINX не пропускает такой запрос и возвращает ответ 404. Мне нужно, что бы URL заканчивался именно расширением *.png.

**Обновление**

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    charset utf-8;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #root /var/www/example.com/web;

    server {
      listen      80 default_server;
      server_name "";
      rewrite     ^(.*)$ http://example.com/ permanent;
    }
    server {
        listen       192.168.6.58:80;
        server_name  example.com;
        root /var/www/protrader.org/web;

        charset utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 200m;


        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            location ~\.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
            }
        }

    location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css|svg|woff)$ {
        expires max;
    }

}
```

Comment: Что бы не давать общих рекомендаций - покажите вашу конфигурацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите `png` из списка расширений в этом location'е: `location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css|svg|woff)$`.

Добавьте для него отдельный location и в нём добавьте директиву `error_page`, которая при 404-ом ответе будет вести в именованный location с именем, к примеру, not_found.

В этом location'е сделайте перенаправление на 127.0.0.1:9000.

Итого, у вас должна получиться такая конфигурация:

```
server {
    listen       192.168.6.58:80;
    server_name  example.com;
    root /var/www/protrader.org/web;

    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 200m;


    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        location ~\.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|rtf|js|css|svg|woff)$ {
        expires max;
    }

    location @not_found {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.png$ {
        error_page 404 = @not_found;
    }
}
```